# WSO2 ESB applying security policies at binding hierarchy

Tags: security, binding, wso2, policy, wso2-esb

I am trying to apply multiple security policies to a proxy service defined in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3.
I need to apply one policy at operation level and other at message level.

I  am using source view to directly define proxy service instead of using Web UI/Policy Editor.

I tried defining each policy as described here:

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/Policies+for+Service

but generated WSDL shows it is getting applied at wrong hierarchy.

Please advice if this capability is supported in WSO2 ESB or am I doing wrong!

My Proxy

```
<proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target endpoint="SimpleStockQuoteService_noSuspendOnFailure_TCPMon">
        <inSequence>
            <header xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" name="wsse:Security" action="remove"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL uri="file:repository/samples/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_3.wsdl"/>
    <policy key="sec_operation-Policy"/>
    <policy key="sec_InOut-Policy"/>
    <enableSec/>
</proxy>
```

My message level Policy

```
<wsp:PolicyAttachment wsu:Id="Service_message_policy_attachment" 
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
            xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
            xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:AppliesTo>
<policy-subject identifier="binding:soap11/operation:getQuote/in"/>
<policy-subject identifier="binding:soap12/operation:getQuote/in"/>
</wsp:AppliesTo>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="Service_message_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body />
               <sp:Header Name="To"
                  Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
               <sp:Header Name="From"
                  Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
               <sp:Header Name="FaultTo"
                  Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
               <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo"
                  Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
               <sp:Header Name="MessageID"
                  Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
               <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo"
                  Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
               <sp:Header Name="Action"
                  Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
            </sp:SignedParts>
            <sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:Body />
            </sp:EncryptedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
</wsp:PolicyAttachment>
```

Comment: This functionality is of course supported. May be you have missed something or seeing a bug. To clarify, by "operation level" you meant binding operation level, right?

Comment: I was trying to find a way to apply multiple security policies to different policy-subjects without manually editing through WSO2 ESB policy editor.  I was expecting there may be a way to define it through Synapse Configuration Language.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the policy through policy editor to apply the policy to different policy subjects in the binding hierarchy. You may refer to [Securing request and response messages with different security policies](http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2011/09/different-security-policies-for-in-out.html) which walks though a sample that demonstrates how to apply different security policies to in and out messages.

This sample directly edits the `services.xml` of an axis2 service.

You will get the same effect if you change the policy through policy editor of ESB and save.

If it still doesn't work for you, please attach the edited policy.xml and the resulted wsdl which will help to provide more insight into the issue.

Comment: Thank you for point me to the right example. I am trying to accomplish  similar multi-policy binding for each endpoint references(EPR) in a single WSDL which is exposing a backend secured web service through WSO2 ESB. Using ESB, I want to modify and route incoming  requests to appropriate backend service endpoint based on the  incoming  security token(UT or X509). 

The goal is to configure my STS proxy that will expose WSDL similar to following WSDL
    http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/services/sts/sts-war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/ws-trust-1.4-service.wsdl

Comment: I noticed WSO2 ESB generate proxy endpoints automatically(http https soap sopa12). How do I control the generation of those endpoints? In my case I need one for each policy and all should be HTTP. 

---
From your explanation, I understand that it is not possible to apply multiple security policies to different policy subjects in the binding hierarchy using Synapse Configuration Language. I will try it through policy editor.

Answer (score 2):

This is supported by WSO2 ESB.

Actually the problem is with the message level policy that you are trying to engage. You are trying to provide a Policy Attachment element, not a policy element. This approach works if you are trying to engage multiple policies to an Axis2 service through its services.xml. But if you are using the Carbon policy editor, it expects you to provide a valid policy element.

Following policy element can be derived from the policy attachment element you have used.

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Service_message_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <sp:Body />
                <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
            </sp:SignedParts>
            <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <sp:Body />
            </sp:EncryptedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found some potential solutions and like to share with you.

Problem 1: Unable to apply security policies  at granular level.

Solution :

I was able to apply security policies  at

1.) root level

2.) operation level and

3.) message level

using ***operationName*** & ***operationNamespace***

```
<proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target endpoint="SimpleStockQuoteService_noSuspendOnFailure_TCPMon">
        <inSequence>
            <header xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" name="wsse:Security" action="remove"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL uri="file:repository/samples/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_3.wsdl"/>
    <!-- Default policy for all operations   -->
    <policy key="sec_SigOnly"/>
    <!--  policy for  getFullQuote operation , in and Out message   -->
    <policy key="SigEncrSTS" operationName="getFullQuote" operationNamespace="http://services.samples"/>
    <!--  policy for  getQuote operation , in  message   -->
    <policy key="sec_InOut-Policy" operationName="getQuote" operationNamespace="http://services.samples" type="in"/>
    <enableSec/>
</proxy>
```

Problem 2: when a proxy service is deployed,  published WSDL is automatically generated and we have limited/no control to customize it.

Solution : 
Using  Property ***useOriginalwsdl***,  I was able to publish original supplied WSDL with only IP/Port changed  to Proxy IP/Port.

```
<proxy name="STSProxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target endpoint="PingSTS_UT">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="preserveProcessedHeaders" value="true" scope="default"/>
            <log level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL key="wsdl_sts"/>
    <parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
```

I wish WSO2 support to apply both of those solutions at the same time. i.e., able to control how published WSDL is generated and apply security policies at granular level.

PS:  When Security Polices are applied by directly editing in Source View, the UI is still showing **Unsecured** . it will only show **Secured** when built-in security policies are applied through Web UI or the policy name match to one of the built-in policy